# How to resize a cube to match the negative space between two planes in geonodes?

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes

*Edit: To be clear, I know how to resize a cube just by changing the the scale or dimensions of the model. I'm trying to figure out how to have the scale and rotation of a cube dynamically update to be exactly the size of the space between two planes that are being dynamically moved by a geometry node tree driven by a scenetime node. Thanks!*

I'm creating a timeskip animation with a panel split background coming in, a clock illustrating the elapsed time, and the panel background splitting out to the sides again. It's all done in geonodes.

I'm trying to set up a box in the space between the collapsing panels that will hide the clockface until the panels have come in. I've got it set up with a NOR Boolean node and Delete Geometries, but I can't figure out how to tie the sides of the box to the edge of the panels. The rotation of the panels is dynamically determined by the position of the clock hands and the position is determined by number of frames used by the panel wipe.

I feel like there's a simple solution, but this is my first geonodes project, so I just don't know enough to connect the dots.

TLDR: I'd like to define the size, rotation, and position of the highlighted box to align with the edge of the panels as they sweep in.

Thanks a bunch!

*(note, I changed some of the images to jpgs because the pngs were too big - the background is supposed to be transparent for all of them)*

EDIT
Well, heck, I went to get a screenshot of the panel split at the end of the animation and found another bug - apparently my Delete Geometry Boolean Box setup only works when the box is square to the x-y axis. Any advice on confining the Delete Geometry effect to the inside of the box even when rotated? Maybe scrap the box defining the negative space and switch to two boxes that imitate the panel?

[image: clock without the Delete Geometry Node active]

[image: clock with the Delete Geometry Node active]

[image: Alpha Wipe Geometry Nodegroup]

[image: The effect I'm going for, but dynamically animated]

[image: This is supposed to only be disappearing within the bounds of the box]

Comment: Resizing a cube to fit between two planes is trivial... The default Cube node's settings spawn a cube with a side of 1. So scaling the cube by a factor equal the distance between planes will yield a cube of the right size to fill that distance. For example, if the distance between planes is 15 meters, a 1 meter cube scaled 15 times yields 15 meters dimension as well...

Answer (score 0):

*(Using Blender 3.6.8)*

Assuming the "collapsing panels" are like sliding doors, here is a proposal made with geometry nodes relying on planes to be symmetrical:

[image: Results]

[image: GN Zoom]

[image: GN Full]

**Resources:** [image]

Comment: Thanks for responding! But I found a better solution than what I was shooting for. I think. Shader issues now. Anyway - I started this whole project following a short tutorial for a simple panel split animation, and kept piling more and more features on. I finally got a solution that kind of worked but I don't think my trig was right. It was good enough though. I woke up the next morning realizing I could use static panel models and a boolean mesh modifier. For whatever reason it destroys the fps, but since I'm rendering in EVEE, it doesn't matter much. 30 secs vs 2 min. Thanks again though!